# Что вернет Xpath в PHP для XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Есть код, который применен к XML

```
list = $xpath->query('./namespace::*', $node)
```

Что по идее должно вернуться в результате выполнения?

Comment: может ничего не вернуть

Comment: @splash58 а все же, что он должен вернуть
Не совсем понятна запись './namespace::*'